# How to manipulate 2d image as different objects in game

Tags: image-processing, game-development

Hello Im very new to this so I don't even know what this process is called exactly.
Im posting image of flappy bird here in which it consist all the objects day, night, birds, font etc Here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQZ5e.png

So how to use them in 2D game? this is just example i have used. How to manipulate different objects at different coordinates ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather question for [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site question, although from my knowledge as an amateur game developer, you just have to crop particular areas in the bitmap image and extract specific bitmaps and assigns them to specific objects in the game like

```
Landscape *landscapeDay = new Landscape("uQZ5e.png", 0, 0, 50, 100);
Landscape *landscapeNight = new Landscape("uQZ5e.png", 50, 0, 50, 100);
BitmapString *getReadyString = new BitmapString("uQZ5e.png", 100, 20, 40, 10, "Get Ready!");
// etc. LandScape and BitmapStrings are classes holding particular bitmaps with
// additional information needed in the game. Their constructors gets the 
// position of image in the bigger bitmap in the way x, y, width, height
```

Of course this is one of the possibly attempts. You load all bitmaps when the game is initializing or later if you don't have enough resources. But as I said, my experience in game dev is rather amateur so you'd better ask on specifoc stack exchange site to get to know how professionals do it.